# same code executing differently

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a minesweeper game, but I am stuck on adding an interface to a blank field. 
Why is this? I can't identify the problem, as the code that is supposed to do it works! The answer changes when you add the input statements

### Without input

```
import string
def add_markers(grid,alphabet):
    top = [' ']
    for count in range(len(grid[0])):
        top.append(alphabet[count])

    grid.insert(0,top)
    for row_num in range(len(grid)):
        if row_num != 0:
            grid[row_num].insert(0,row_num)

    return grid
blank = [['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]
user_grid = add_markers(blank, list(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase))
print(user_grid)
```

Outputs correct grid, `[[' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], [1, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], [2, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], [3, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], [4, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], [5, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]`

### With input

```
import random, string

def add_markers(grid,alphabet):
    top = [' ']
    for count in range(len(grid[0])):
        top.append(alphabet[count])

    grid.insert(0,top)
    for row_num in range(len(grid)):
        if row_num != 0:
            grid[row_num].insert(0,row_num)

    return grid

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase)
length = int(input('length of field > '))
height = int(input('height of field > '))
bombs = int(input('number of bombs > '))
blank = [length * ['#']] * height

user_grid = add_markers(blank, alphabet)
print(user_grid)
```

Outputs:
`[[' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]`

Comment: Sorry Pete but people can't fully debug your script. You'll need to localize the problem, add it here, describe what you're trying to do and supply the code in the question body (and not redirect us to `repl.it`).

Comment: I fixed the problem, sorry

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard I have changed it so it's easier to see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you construct blank. Doing it the way you're currently using, you actually create multiple references to the same list.

here's an example of what happens when you construct it the way you do now:

```
in: blank[0].append(1)
in: blank
out: [['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 1], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 1], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 1], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 1], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 1]]
```

As since all of the lists contained in blank are actually just references to the same list, making a change to any of them, will affect them all.

Here's an easy solution to your problem, replace you blank constructor with this:

```
for i in range(length):
    blank.append([])
    for j in range(height):
        blank[i].append('#')
```

This way, you will  actually construct independent lists.

Example behaviour, compliant with what you need:

```
in: blank[0].append(1)
in: blank
out: [['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 1], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]
```